# Removing website from Google ranking under unwanted keyword

Tags: seo

Is there any way to remove a website from appearing in Google search results under an unwanted keyword?

About a year ago, I added a featured project to a company website. This page included the client's name - she requested we keep the project anonymous so we removed any mention of her name and any identifying details.

Today - when you Google her name, our website homepage comes up regardless of her name not being on our website. I've even checked Google's cached page.

I'm stumped as to why our site, without any matching keywords would appear above other relevant results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google normally takes a snapshot of what contents originally appear on a page for the first time as they are discovered. Google can be rather stubborn on dropping keywords when originally they was intended, even through it was a mistake to begin Google is non the wiser.

The process of dropping a keyword can take many months and you should insure that you have covered all areas:

1. No mention of name on the page content
2. No mention of the name in the hidden content such as Title, Meta Descriptions, Keywords, Alt Tags
3. No off site links, if someone is linking to the website with 'her name' like a profile from a forum or signature can cause this so check the backlinks.
4. Check Authorship / Publisher information on Webmaster Tools and Google Plus, these can be linked and that could add to the problem.
5. Ultimately the issue you have is time, it takes a long time to drop a keyword from Google.